# Understanding solution to Hilzer's Barbershop Problem

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, semaphore

### Problem

This is a problem from "The Little Book Of Semaphores".

> Our barbershop has three chairs, three barbers, and a waiting area
>   that can accommodate four customers on a sofa and that has standing
>   room for additional customers. Fire codes limit the total number of
>   customers in the shop to 20.
>
> A customer will not enter the shop if it is filled to capacity with
>   other customers. Once inside, the customer takes a seat on the sofa or
>   stands if the sofa is filled. When a barber is free, the customer that
>   has been on the sofa the longest is served and, if there are any
>   standing customers, the one that has been in the shop the longest
>   takes a seat on the sofa. When a customer’s haircut is finished, any
>   barber can accept payment, but because there is only one cash
>   register, payment is accepted for one customer at a time. The bar-
>   bers divide their time among cutting hair, accepting payment, and
>   sleeping in their chair waiting for a customer.

### Book's solution

Below is the book's solution:

**Shared variables**

```
customers = 0
mutex = Semaphore(1)
mutex2 = Semaphore(1)
sofa = Semaphore(4)
customer1 = Semaphore(0)
customer2 = Semaphore(0)
payment = Semaphore(0)
receipt = Semaphore(0)
queue1 = []
queue2 = []
```

**Customer thread**

```
self.sem1 = Semaphore(0)
self.sem2 = Semaphore(0)

mutex.wait()
    if customers == 20:
        mutex.signal()
        balk()
    customers += 1
    queue1.append(self.sem1)
mutex.signal()

# enterShop()
customer1.signal()
self.sem1.wait()

sofa.wait()
    # sitOnSofa()
    self.sem1.signal()
    mutex2.wait()
        queue2.append(self.sem2)
    mutex2.signal()
    customer2.signal()
    self.sem2.wait()
sofa.signal()

# getHairCut()

mutex.wait()
    # pay()
    payment.signal()
    receipt.wait()
    customers -= 1
mutex.signal()
```

**Barber thread**

```
customer1.wait()
mutex.wait()
    sem = queue1.pop(0)
    sem.signal()
    sem.wait()
mutex.signal()

customer2.wait()
mutex2.wait()
    sem2 = queue2.pop(0)
    sem2.signal()
mutex2.signal()

# cutHair()
payment.wait()
# acceptPayment()
receipt.signal()
```

### Question

As I understood it, the following steps can happen when the first customer (Customer 1) comes in and a barber (Barber 1) is sleeping on `customer1`:

1. Customer 1 adds its own semaphore to `queue1`, signals `customer1`, and waits on its own semaphore.
2. Barber 1 wakes up, pops Customer 1's semaphore from the `customer1` queue, signals it (waking up Customer 1), and waits on it. At this moment, Barber 1 holds `mutex`, so no other free barber can let a customer in before Barber 1 gets to wake up and release `mutex`.
3. Customer 1 wakes up, passes through `sofa` (subtracting it and making it 3), and signals its own semaphore (waking up Barber 1).
4. Barber 1 wakes up and signals `mutex`.

At this point, there is nothing stopping another customer from going through the same process, and eventually getting to `queue2` before Customer 1.

So, I'm having trouble understanding how the book's solution enforces the constraint that "if there are any standing customers, the one that has been in the shop the longest takes a seat on the sofa".

To enforce the order, it seems like the **Customer thread** should signal its `self.sem1` only after it adds itself to `queue2`, not before.

Could someone help me understand this solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the barber thread pulls customers from the head of queue2, which represents the sofa, so once the barber pulls a customer, that customer is the one waiting for the longest time on the sofa.

Second, note that once a customer is pulled out of queue2, the hair cut itself does not take any time, and the customer moves to payment. So the way it is written, customers are pulled from the queue and moved the payment immediately. Haircut is instantaneous.

So if another customer comes and moves through the queues, the only way it can be picked is if there is another barber and the second customer is at the head of the queue. But, if the second customer is at the head of the queue, that means another barber already picked the first customer. So, that really cannot happen.

About your question regarding `self.sem1`: its purpose is to wake up the customer once the customer is picked from the queue. `sem1` corresponds to the queue for customers standing, `sem2` corresponds to the sofa. The customer adds the semaphore to the queue, and waits on it, so when the barber thread picks it up, it can wake up the customer. So it can't really enforce ordering, it is there to wake up the customer when he/she changes location. The ordering is enforced by the queue.